# Getting" ValueError: truncate requires a sorted index" While Trying to Truncate a dataframe for either SELECTING or SLICING

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering, subset, truncate

#### Overview:

##### SUBSETTING means extracting value(s) from a dataframe. This can be done in 4 ways:

- 1] SELECTING [Extracting COLUMNS]
- 2] SLICING
  [Extracting ROWS] and
- 3] INDEXING [Extracting Both Columns + Rows]
- 4] FILTERING [Extracting Both Columns + Rows Based on CONDITIONS]

So while using a Method called: TRUNCATE() for Selecting or Slicing for any of the first 2 methods:

#### Script:

`df.truncate(before='Team', after='Yellow_Cards', axis = 'columns')`

#### Error:

ValueError: truncate requires a sorted index

Steps Took for the Resolution:
-> Identified that the Dataframe Index is Sorted from 0 to 15 in ascending

-> Tried:

`df[['Team', 'Shooting Accuracy']].head(3)` #Select MULTIPLE Columns

`df.iloc[:,[0,1]]`

`df. loc[:, ['Team', 'Shooting Accuracy']]`

- Was able to SORT with the above 3 Code lines

#### SOLUTION:

-> Identified that the Column/Features names also should be Sorted In Alphabetic / Numeric Order

- Code for Resolution: using the "sort_index" method for pandas
- `df.sort_index(axis = 1, ascending=True, inplace=True)`